# react-i18next - How to access nested keys in a js file with dynamic values using the t()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-i18next

Please how do I call action[EDIT].title using t() function in order to return the string "Edit". The EN.js file that contains my translation is like this

```
// EN.js

const EDIT = "EDIT";
const DELETE = "DELETE";

action: {
    [EDIT]: {
      title: 'Edit',
    },
    [DELETE]: {
      title: 'Delete',
    },
}
```

and my config is

```
// i18n.js

const resources = {
  en: {
    translation: EN
  },
  de: {
    translation: DE
  },
};
i18next
  .use(initReactI18next)
  .init({
    resources,
    lng: 'en',
    fallbackLng: 'en',
    interpolation: {
      escapeValue: false,
    },
    debug: true,
  });

export default i18next;
```

I expect for  t(action[EDIT].title) to return the string 'Edit'

Comment: Did you try `t("EDIT")` ?  See the samples [here](https://react.i18next.com/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I encountered this kind of blocker and using a dot notation instead of bracket notation worked for me. I didn't need to modify the translation file tho but simply doing `t('action.EDIT.title')` worked.

Answer (score 0):

To access the nested keys in your translation file with dynamic values, you should modify your translation object to include a namespace or key path. Then, you can use the t() function with the path.

First, update your EN.js file to include a namespace or key path for the action objects:

```
// EN.js
const EDIT = "EDIT";
const DELETE = "DELETE";

const EN = {
  action: {
    [EDIT]: {
      title: 'Edit',
    },
    [DELETE]: {
      title: 'Delete',
    },
  },
};

export default EN;
```

Now, you can access the nested key using the t() function like this:

```
 const editTitle = t('action.EDIT.title');
```